# Arduino Variable Data Type?

Tags: programming, arduino-mega, data-type

Is there a variable data type available for Arduino? I have a class that should have a member that will differ in data type, in the past I have used the "variable" keyword in c++ but when I tried to use it the compiler yelled at me. I searched online and found a couple of articles that mentioned that if you are using an alternate GUI (I am using eclipse mars) that you can enable the feature but I can not find the correct settings as the examples I had found were for Juno and below.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish

```
class DisplayItem{

   public:
   variant *displayVar;

   void Display(){
      Serial.println(displayVar);
   }
}

int intDisplay;
String strDisplay;

DisplayItem item();
item.displayVar = &intDisplay;
item.Display();
item.displayVar = &strDisplay;
item.Display();
```

I realize I could create a overloaded function to display different data types but it would be allot easier if I could simply assign a reference to a variant datatype and reuse the variable.

---

**Edit**

So after looking through the answers I think I have this figured out. I needed to keep track of which variable was being set, I put together a quick example in hopes it will help someone else out with the same question.

```
class DisplayItem{

   private:
   int iVarType;

   union{
      int *i;
      float *f;
   } displayVar;

   public:
   void SetVar(int *var){
      displayVar.i = var;
      iVarType = 0;
   }

   void SetVar(float *var){
      displayVar.f = var;
      iVarType = 1;
   }

   void Display(){
      if (iVarType == 0){
         Serial.println(displayVar.i);
      }else if (iVarType == 1){
         Serial.println(displayVar.f);
      }
   }
}

int intDisplay = 1;
float floatDisplay = 0.123;

DisplayItem item();
item.SetVar(&intDisplay);
item.Display();
item.SetVar(&floatDisplay);
item.Display();
```

Will Display:

```
1
0.123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the situation illustrated in the question – displaying data – polymorphic functions already exist, and might as well be used in this case.  Specifically, use the `Streaming.h` [contributed library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Libraries).  It adds some “syntactic sugar” to Arduino C.  At compile time it converts C++-like `<<` Serial stream operators to `Serial.print` statements, without increasing code size.  You can install it via [`Streaming5.zip`](http://arduiniana.org/Streaming/Streaming5.zip) from [arduiniana.org](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/) .

In other cases, a `union` data structure allows treating an area of memory different ways.  Wikipedia's *[Union type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type)* article explains the general idea.  See eg [tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) for `union` syntax and usage.  For some reason, arduino.cc's [Language Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage) page hasn't got `union` on its list of language features.  However, mcgurrin.com has a page called *[There is Power in a Union](http://www.mcgurrin.com/robots/?p=127)* that codes a simple Arduino C example two ways (where `bearing` is an `int`):

```
higherByte = compass.read();
lowerByte = compass.read();
bearing = ((higherByte<<8)+lowerByte)/10
```

-vs-

```
union Data {
  byte b[2];
  int value;
};
...
union Data data;
data.b[0] = compass.read();
data.b[1] = compass.read();
bearing = data.value/10;
```

Comment: Would you then use sizeof(data.b[0]) to determine if the variable has been used or is there a better way?

Comment: `sizeof data.b[0]` (the parentheses aren't needed if the argument is a variable rather than a type) is a constant, so has no bearing on whether a section of memory has been set to a value.  Use a separate flag variable or some program flow analysis to keep track of whether a cell is occupied.  Note, `union` is most useful in certain type conversions (eg changing endianness among integer types or getting the exponent field of a `float`) or when marshalling data for export, eg filling a buffer with a variety of data items before using a `write` to send the buffer on its way.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing.  The whole concept of "type" only exists during compilation, not at run-time.

However, you can "emulate" it using "setters" and keeping your own internal state information:

```
class Thing {
    private:
        String *strvar;
        int intvar;
        int type;

    public:
        void set(int val) {
            intvar = val;
            type = 1;
        }
        void set(String &str) {
            strval = &str;
            type = 2;
        }
        void Display() {
            if (type == 1) {
                Serial.print("Value: ");
                Serial.println(intval);
            } else if (type == 2) {
                Serial.print("String: ");
                Serial.println(strval);
            } else {
                Serial.println("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
};

Thing t;
String s = "This is a string";
int i = 23;
t.set(s);
t.Display();
t.set(i);
t.Display();
```

The multiple functions named the same but with different parameters are *overloaded*. The best match is picked at compile time.

Comment: I have in my question about using overloaded functions, I was hoping that there was a variable datatype as I have seen it in other c++ platforms. But if this is the only way to accomplish this I guess I don't have much choice.

Comment: It's down to the IDE preprocessing your code with its own keywords. The closest is a `void *` pointer which can point to the memory of any data type, however it doesn't have any concept of what that datatype is - it's just memory.

Comment: Actually modern C++ provides run-time type information for classes. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) for some examples. Unfortunately this is often disabled when compiling for small scale embedded systems to reduce memory foot-print. Last, in @Majenko 's example the value could be stored in a union. See [Cosa/Types.h univ16_t and univ32_t](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/Types.h#L109) for examples of universal type.

Comment: You mean `dynamic_cast`? Only useful when you're working with polymorphism.